# Microsoft Access Combo boxes and vba code 2007

Tags: vba, combobox

I have two combo boxes each with different drop down items

Combo box 1:  New, Sold, Retired
Combo box 2:  Unallocated, Retired, Reworked, Shipped

I want it so when the user selects New or Retired from comobo box one those corresponding values show up in combo box two.

I used the on click sub for combo box 1

```
If Me.combox1.Value = "New" Then
Me.combox2.Value = "Unallocated"
End If

If Me.combox1.Value ="Retired" Then
Me.combox2.Value = "Retired"
End If
```

I don't need the two boxes to be synchronized for all the values just those two.

I am just learning VBA code for access, so i am unsure of the best way to make this happen.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Access forms, but your code looks reasonable. What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
If Me.combox1.Value = "New" Then
Me.combox2.Value = "Unallocated"
ElseIf Me.combox1.Value ="Retired" Then
Me.combox2.Value = "Retired"
Else
'do nothing
End If
```